# Value of an Attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I need valid XSD for the following XML:

```
<Element Name="myElement" Value="true" />
```

This is what I got so far, but it misses the definition for `value`:

```
<xs:element name="Element" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="Name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Unfortunately I haven't found out yet, how to implement the definition for `value`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, you've got a start. Are you asking for someone here to finish it for you?  Do you have a specific question besides that?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to add the definition for `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You handle `Name` like this:

```
<xs:attribute name="Name"/>
```

So simply do the same for `Value`:

```
<xs:attribute name="Value"/>
```

Here is the final XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Element" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="Name"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Value"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

See more examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp

Comment: Of course, you might also want to add a type. If the only values that `Value` can take are 'true' and 'false', for example, then you could add `type="xs:boolean"`. But we can't infer the possible set of values from one example instance.